# When was the design for the "original" Enterprise (NX-01) created?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, uss-enterprise, star-trek-first-contact

While watching *Star Trek: First Contact*, I noticed that Captain Picard keeps a case with models of all the previous *Enterprises*, including what seemed to me to be the *Enterprise* NX-01.
[image]
This ship first appeared in the TV show *Star Trek: Enterprise*, which began in the early 2000s. When was the design of the ship first finalized to look the way it did? Had the design appeared in a previous episode that I was not aware of, or was this a preview to what we would se in *Enterprise*?

Comment: I'm assuming the ship that you thought was the the _NX-01_ was the ship on the far right? Those are the nacelles of the _Enterprise E_.

Comment: I know that I didn't see the Enterprise-E. I'll have to watch First Contact again, but I am 90% sure that I saw the NX-01. I wish there was a better image.

Comment: @DonatelloSwansino - there are better images - from the production designer himself, of the set of the film you are asking about, as well as a statement from the same that the NX is in *no way* depicted because it was 5 years from being designed in real-life. See my answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None of the ships in the case resemble the NX-01 except in as much as the NX was designed to resemble the ships already depicted.

**The ships displayed are the Constitution class (TOS), A, B, C, D and E**

Eaves himself [states](https://johneaves.wordpress.com/2009/06/26/the-golden-enterprise/#comment-5244) as to the NX-01's apparent absence:

> "it hadn’t even been invented yet!!! this was at least 5 years before
>   Enterprise came out. Sorry"

[Source: John Eaves - Star Trek First Contact production designer](https://johneaves.wordpress.com/2009/06/26/the-golden-enterprise/)

[image]

What of **Star Trek Nemesis**? One may be forgiven for thinking that since **Star Trek: Enterprise** had started production, perhaps the NX-01 was depicted as a gold model on the Enterprise-E in that film. Also - no:

[Interview with John Eaves](http://www.startrek.com/article/guest-blog-the-lineage-of-ships-that-bear-the-name-enterprise) discussing **Star Trek: Nemesis** ships:

> Moving ahead another couple of years, to Star Trek Nemesis, we are
>   back to the observation lounge in what would be the Big E's final
>   mission. **The lounge set got a big face lift and the addition of a
>   much-larger display area for the Enterprise models. Instead of six
>   ships, this time there were going to be 12**. For the second case, we
>   built the Voyager, the Excelsior, the Grissom, the Reliant and under
>   construction were the Phoenix and the Defiant. The deadline for these
>   models moved when the filming scheduled changed the set order, and the
>   observation lounge got moved up considerably. **To make a long story
>   short, the additional models didn't make it to the set and instead the
>   E models were duplicated in pairs on either side of the viewing
>   screen.**

Comment: My personal take is that the NX-01 only became named "Enterprise" after the events in "First Contact" altered the timeline.  In the original unaltered timeline the NX-01 was named "Dauntless" as suggested by the Voyager episode "Hope and Fear".  After Picard and the Enterprise returned home, Dulmer and Luscly interviewed him and presented him with an NX-01 model to put in the display case.

Comment: The Enterprise E never had an NX model @EmsleyWyatt - even in Nemesis (which might fit your theory of the NX being presented after the events of First Contact) - however, the Nemesis E has no NX model - just the same gold ships - again - from John Eaves, production designer on the films: http://www.startrek.com/article/guest-blog-the-lineage-of-ships-that-bear-the-name-enterprise

Comment: Blame it on Q...

Comment: If they depict Enterprise A, B, C, D and E, what is the 6th model?

Comment: NCC-1701 is the original Constitution and Constitution refit (destroyed in ST III); the model is the pre-refit. NCC-1701-A is the second Constitution Refit to bear the name given to Kirk in ST IV (and the model shown) . NCC-1701-B is the Excelsior Class seen in *Generations*. NCC-1701-C is the Ambassador Class destroyed by Romulans defending a Klingon colony in 2344. NCC-1701-D is the Galaxy Class ship commanded by Picard. NCC-1701-E is the Sovereign Class also commanded by Picard. That's six.

Comment: @JohnP [Relevant drunk Scotty scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1A1TZQk5Wgk)

Answer (score 0):

The *Enterprise* NX-01 was not affiliated with the United Federation of Planets like the other *Enterprise*s, hence the prefix "U.S.S." (United StarShip or United SpaceShip), the NX-01 did not have a prefix, but in my opinion the NX-01 should have been U.E.S. (United Earth Ship); note: that the *Fortunate Son* and the *Horizon* had the prefix "E.C.S." (Earth Cargo Ship). That being said, when the Federation was formed, they started over at NX-01 and launched the U.S.S. *Dauntless* NX-01, with the "U.S.S." prefix. This should explain why when ever anyone mentions the original *Enterprise*, why they are referring to Kirk's Enterprise is because they are actually referring to the original *Enterprise* built by the Federation. Even the NX-01 was not the original *Enterprise*, there are plenty of *Enterprise*s that came before that, such as the H.M.S. *Enterprize* or the shuttlecraft *Enterprise* OV-101 and of course the U.S.S. *Enterprise* CVN-65 which was once visited by Chekhov and Uhura in Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home.

The dedication plaque of the *Enterprise*-E states "Sixth Starship to bear the name".
[image]